# how to include lvl-license project with android gradle project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android gradle project it's now not compiling because it's looking for license classes so i tried to include them as following in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    **compile project(':lvl-licensing').projectDir = new File(projectDir, '../lvl-licensing/library'**)
}
```

problem is that for some reason i still get this:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':myproject'.
> Project with path ':lvl-licensing' could not be found in project ':myproject'.
```

how can i include the `lvl-license/library` project in my project using `gradle`? why is it complaining? I do have the project in that folder with `build.gradle` and I can compile that `lvl-license/library` project separately.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `lvl-licensing` file to your `settings.gradle` file as well. Also, that library can't be outside the root directory of your project; it looks like you're trying to place the library in a sibling directory to your project.

If you put the library under your project root, you don't need to do the gymnastics with the path in your `compile project` statement.

Comment: Hi

I forgot to mention i already have this in my settings.gradle

include ':lvl-licensing'
project(':lvl-licensing').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../lvl-licensing/library')

in my orig project